# Fulltext search, no results?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, codeigniter, search

I'm trying to implement a database search, by using `match`, `against` and `fulltext indexing`. So, when I did the search, it did not work as expect, no errors and no results was given. I'm querying by using Codeigniter.

Here is my PHP query code:

```
$clean_keyword = trim($keywords); //$keyword is passed to the function`
$this->db->select('question, answer')
         ->from('QA')
         ->where('MATCH(question) AGAINST("'.$clean_keyword.'")', null, FALSE);  
$query = $this->db->get(); //execute the previous statement and save the result in a variable.
```

No errors from codeigniter/MySQL was given.

I tried to debug the `$query` variable by doing `var_dump($query)`, see the results (*N.B. The important part is `result_array` with `size=0`*):

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)[19]
  public 'conn_id' => resource(30, mysql link persistent)
  public 'result_id' => resource(38, mysql result)
  public 'result_array' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'custom_result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'current_row' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => int 0
  public 'row_data' => null
```

MySQL table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `QA` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `u_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `question` (`question`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Comment: what is in $clean_keyword ? or may be it doesnot match results

Comment: @MoyedAnsari updated, thanks for pointing me to `$clean_keyword` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no errors in my code/database schema or anything, I just realized that `FULLTEXT search` doesn't show matches that only contains 1 word, example:
if I query this:
`SELECT * FROM QA WHERE MATCH(question) AGAINST('drive');`
and there is one question with the word `drive` ONLY, ill get no matches.
But if i alter the `drive` question column, to something like `how to drive` ill get a match.